# How to make QTableWidget adjust to minimal space

Tags: python, pyqt, resize, pyqt5, qtablewidget

Using PyQt5 with Python, I am trying to create a grid of QTableWidgets with various numbers of cells. I make the tables adjustable in size so that they fit nicely to the available size of the window. I am able to adjust the tables correctly while increasing the window size, that is, the cells maintain equal sizes and the QTableWidgets adjust their sizes to the free space. This adjustment is done by overwriting the resizeEvent of QTableWidget class and by setting row and column stretches for QGridLayout. This is illustrated in the figure below.

[image: screenshot]

However, while making the QMainWindow smaller, the QTableWidgets at some point become unable to adjust their sizes smaller.

[image: screenshot]

Is it possible to enable the QTableWidgets to get smaller in sizes when making the window smaller? Clearly, the values in the cells would enable this.

A code with which I have implemented the above table grids is given below.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidget, QWidget

class MyTable(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, r, c):
        super().__init__(r, c)
        self.horizontalHeader().hide()
        self.verticalHeader().hide()                
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        eh          = event.size().height()
        ew          = event.size().width()
        ehremain    = eh
        eqremain    = ew
        rh          = int(eh // self.rowCount())
        cw          = int(ew // self.columnCount())
        for i in range(self.rowCount()-1):
            self.setRowHeight(i, rh)
            ehremain -= rh
        self.setRowHeight(self.rowCount()-1, ehremain)
        for j in range(self.columnCount()-1):
            self.setColumnWidth(j, cw)
            eqremain -= cw
        self.setColumnWidth(self.columnCount()-1, eqremain)

class TableGrid(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.table1 = MyTable(1,1)
        self.table2 = MyTable(1,3)
        self.table3 = MyTable(3,1)
        self.table4 = MyTable(3,3)
        grid_layout = QGridLayout()
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.table1, 0,0)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.table2, 0,1)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.table3, 1,0)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.table4, 1,1)
        grid_layout.setRowStretch(0,1)
        grid_layout.setRowStretch(1,3)
        grid_layout.setColumnStretch(0,1)
        grid_layout.setColumnStretch(1,3)
        self.setLayout(grid_layout)
        self.show()

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.table_grid = TableGrid()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table_grid)
        self.show()

if __name__ =="__main__":
    app     = QApplication.instance() # checks if QApplication already exists
    if not app: # create QApplication if it doesnt exist 
        app    = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
    sheet   = Window()
    app.exec_()
    #sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tables won't resize smaller than their default minimum size. So just choose a more appropriate value, like this:

```
class MyTable(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, r, c):
        ...
        self.setMinimumSize(40, 40)
```

Comment: That did the job, many thanks! As a matter of fact, I did try to solve this issue by setting the minimum sizes of the widgets to 0. However, it seems that setting this property to 0 has no effect, and the given value must be strictly positive instead.